# How can I instantly add a control rig to a character?

Tags: rigging

Can Blender take a rig with a skeleton like what comes out of Maximo and add a control rig and IK controls for the hands and feet?

Comment: Did you try Rigify addon? It does exactly, what you're describing.

Comment: I thought Rigify only worked with a characters that has no bones as I've seen only tutorials that always start without any.

Comment: Well, yeah, but why would you need to import some other basic rig if you have one already in the trunk?

Comment: I used to make FBX files to export these rig with just bones, weight paint and shape keys but no IK or control rigs. This time I wish to do it all in Blender. I guess I could destroy the rigs I already made and start over I suppose.